# How to return value in alertHandler

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

In flex 3.5 I have to manager Alert.show with alertHandler function. In that function there is no return value is possible. But i Need to get some value from that. Is it possible to write as return one value without writing alertHandler function. If alertHandler in the sence, how to return one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value comes through the CloseEvent which is passed into your listener. `event.detail` if I remember correctly. So something like `event.detail == Alert.Yes` would be the logic if someone clicks "Yes."